# Size of file using Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, android-internal-storage

I'm using:

```
FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

to store strings of data into the file **FILENAME**. I want to ensure that I will stop appending any more strings when the string within FILENAME has reached 120kB. How do I query the total space taken?

I've tried:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + FILENAME);
Log.i(TAG, "Storage Used (Bytes): " + Long.toString(file.getTotalSpace()));
```

but it returns me a huge number. Could be because the way I'm referencing the directory is wrong?

Comment: Look at File.length()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method length() instead. From documentation

[getTotalSpace](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace()):

> Returns the size of the partition named by this abstract pathname.

[length](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length()):

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

So getTotalSpace is for checking information about folders or drives.